# Include file/template foreach user

Tags: php, templates, variables, include

I'm trying to load a "template" file for each user.

The file loads for each user, so if i have 2 users it loads it two times, but the variables **$user['profileimg']** and **$user['name']** does not.

I have no idé why this wouldn't work, and also i have a feeling this might be a bad practice. So my question is: How do i get this to work / How should i do something like this.

Thx in advance for any help you can provide.

this is the code ive got right now:

**class :**

```
class Cprint 
{
    public static function Template($name, $path = 'template')
    {
         include ROOT_DIR . '/' . $path . '/' . $name . '.php';
    }
}
```

**page.php**

```
foreach($Users->getAll() as $user)
{
   Cprint::Template('userlist_template');
}
```

**userlist_template.php :**

```
<div class="userholder">
   <img class="profileimg" src="<?php echo $user['profileimg'] ?>"/>
   <p><?php echo $user['name'] ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: `$user['profileimg'] and $user['name'] does not.` does not what?

Comment: if i inspect html it shoud be <p>username</p> but it is <p></p>

Comment: Why do you load one template for each user? I think what you want to do is to load a template that looks differently for each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the foreach loop does not transfer the $user data to the template.

You would need to pass the $user data to the template method:

To explain better, the static method `Template` needs an extra parameter ($users). the `Cprint::Template()` method then needs to pass the `$user` array to the `Template()` method as a second parameter

**class**

```
class Cprint 
{
    public static function Template($name, $path = 'template', $user= array())
    {
        include ROOT_DIR . '/' . $path . '/' . $name . '.php';
    } 
}
```

**Page.php**

```
foreach($Users->getAll() as $user)
{
   Cprint::Template('userlist_template', $user);
}
```

Comment: this works thx, is there i way i dont have to specify $user in the class, so i can use it on other stuff as well ?

Comment: I don't think so, my suggestion would be to change `$user = array()` in the method declaration to `$data = array()`, then in `userlist_template.php` file, change your variable names from `$user` to `$data`. This, in the least would allow you to pass any data to the `Template()` method

Comment: I think the way you're doing it at the moment is most logical, the `Template()` method i guess is designed to include a PHP page. Infact, the way you're doing it, is a much simplified version of my own template API. In my own object, I have a `template()` method which i pass the path of the template file as first parameter, and all the data variables as an array in the second parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately the file itself is quite large and heavily integrated with other modules within the site which would make it pretty pointless as a file on its own! I would say though, when designing a template engine, design it well and with lots of thought! Its probably one of the more important parts of a website (if you go down the template route).

Answer (score 0):

When you do `include` the variables the included script see are relative to scope of where its called

so since you call it within the static function of Cprint only variables in that functions scope are seen.

what you need to do is pass the user

```
public static function Template($user,$name, $path = 'template')
{
     include ROOT_DIR . '/' . $path . '/' . $name . '.php';
}
```

and call it appropriately

```
foreach($Users->getAll() as $user)
{
   Cprint::Template($user,'userlist_template');
}
```